# Difference between Active Users and Total User in GA4

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

For a selected date range (last 3 days) I am getting a difference in Active Users and Total Users count. No segment or filter is applied, it is for overall events tracking. I am using Google Analytics 4. If I look for specific events using a filter the value matches. Why is the count different in this case? [image]

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe Active Users are the one who engaged (aka didn't bounce, aka did more than 1 request besides the page view to start a session.

This was what I understood from their API help ([link here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema))

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. I will check myself and mark it solved if correct